# Rails 3 - "to_f" fixes the issue, but I'm not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, charts, floating-point

In my model Reports I have an attribute called :total. In Reports view I show the last 4 entries of this :total attribute (from previous Reports) on a chart. I found that when there wasn't a previous entry, the chart wouldn't render. When I went back and added "to_f" to the calculation, the chart would render and just show "0" where there was no entry. I'm glad it worked, but it was just a wild guess. Why did this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values were probably nil. I'm guessing your formatter wasn't keen on working with nils. However, nil implements a .to_f which returns 0.0, which your formatter could handle without crashing.

i.e.

```
nil.to_f # => 0.0
```

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what happened. The previous entries were nil. Another question, what other methods are there like "to_f" and "to_i"?

Comment: There .to_s string, .to_a array, .to_set if applicable. It sort of varies based on what object you're dealing with.

Comment: You can go like OBJECT.methods.select {|method| method[0,2] == 'to' } to find out.  like  nil.methods.select {|method| method[0,2] == 'to' }, or 'a'.methods.select {|method| method[0,2] == 'to' }, or [:a].methods.select {|method| method[0,2] == 'to' }

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code all I can do is guess.

I'm guessing that report.total was nil for some of the reports in your database and whatever code you are using to make charts can not handle nil values.

For example, `nil/2` will throw an exception but `nil.to_f/2` will not.